# Most accurate ways to calculate Percentile of a huge dataset

Tags: statistics

I am wondering what is the best way of calculating the most accurate percentile of a huge dataset (Billions of data).

I used to assume I got a Normal distribution and use Logarithmic to reduce skewness.

I also used Frequency table to approximate the 99,95,90th percentile.

Is there another way of calculating the percentile as accurately as possible?

Note that even though the performance in R is not that important, The computation last 1 hour or 2 hours doesn't matter than much. I still need a good enough performance to finish the computation within 10 hours.

Comment: Having "billions" of pieces of data isn't particularly large. A standard computer performs on the order of a billion operations per second. It sounds like you don't need to perform too much actual work on the data, so you could just sort the dataset and then retrieve the appropriate indices. As for getting the actual algorithms to perform this, that should be asked on a different site, such as StackOverflow. A first, probably sufficient algorithm would be a binary search --- guess a value, check it, and repeat. This is sort of the idea behind a quicksort too, I suppose

Answer (score 1):

Once you have an approximation to the $90$th percentile, for example, you can make one pass through the data and find the exact value.  Set a range that you are sure the actual $90$th percentile lies in.  Read the data, counting the values that fall below your range, retaining the values in your range, and counting the values above your range.  The better your approximation, the narrower the range can be and the fewer values you need to save.  Then using the counts, you can find the rank in your range that is the exact $90$th percentile.

Comment: then what happens when something like this happens.

Comment: I am sorry misclicked last post...

Comment: So what happens when we got for example: 1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 100, 100...,100.   In this case the 90th percentile by passing and sorting data is 100 which is not the correct value.

Comment: Depending on how many $100$s you have, it could well be the correct value.  Your frequency table will probably show that by itself.  If your values are integers, the frequency table is all you need if you have a bin for all the integers that appear.  You can compute the percentiles directly from it.  I was imagining you have floats so you can't represent the whole distribution in a frequency table.